# How can I delete or remove data from JSON file in Ubuntu 20.04 Apache web server?

Tags: php, html, jquery, json, crud

I'm developing a CRUD operation in JSON. I have two files index.php and action.php. The code is working fine in XAMPP windows and Ubuntu below 18.04 versions. But when I tried to run in Ubuntu 20.04, no CRUD operation is performing.

I tried reinstalling Apache web servers in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 with all similar steps and same permission setting. I installed same versions of php7.4, Mariadb 10 database, and apache2. I checked status of both machines resulting same information. I copied the project in both servers and the CRUD operation is working in Ubuntu 18.04 but not 20.04 version. Then I tried with Ubuntu 16 and Xampp in Windows. That is working fine.
I upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 version and it is also not working. What I came to know is it is not working in Ubuntu Versions above 18.04.

Is it OS problem or web server? I'm totally confused.
Here are index.php and action.php files

Index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

        <title>PHP CRUD Operations with JSON File</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="mt-4 mb-4 text-center text-warning">JSON CRUD operations in PHP | Delete or Remove Data from JSON File</h1>

            <span id="message"></span>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-sm-9">Sample Data</div>
                        <div class="col col-sm-3">
                            <button type="button" id="add_data" class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-end">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="sample_data">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Gender</th>
                                    <th>Age</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="action_modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" id="sample_form">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="dynamic_modal_title"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" />
                        <span id="first_name_error" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" />
                        <span id="last_name_error" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Gender</label>
                        <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Age</label>
                        <input type="number" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />
                        <span id="age_error" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="Add" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="action_button">Add</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    load_data();

    function load_data()
    {
        var seconds = new Date() / 1000;

        $.getJSON("data.json?"+seconds+"", function(data){

            data.sort(function(a,b){

                return b.id - a.id;

            });

            var data_arr = [];

            for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
            {
                var sub_array = {
                    'first_name' : data[count].first_name,
                    'last_name' : data[count].last_name,
                    'gender' : data[count].gender,
                    'age' : data[count].age,
                    'action' : '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-id="'+data[count].id+'">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete" data-id="'+data[count].id+'">Delete</button>'
                };

                data_arr.push(sub_array);
            }

            $('#sample_data').DataTable({
                data : data_arr,
                order : [],
                columns : [
                    { data : "first_name" },
                    { data : "last_name" },
                    { data : "gender" },
                    { data : "age" },
                    { data : "action" }
                ]
            });

        });
    }

    $('#add_data').click(function(){

        $('#dynamic_modal_title').text('Add Data');

        $('#sample_form')[0].reset();

        $('#action').val('Add');

        $('#action_button').text('Add');

        $('.text-danger').text('');

        $('#action_modal').modal('show');

    });

    $('#sample_form').on('submit', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$('#sample_form').serialize(),
            dataType:"JSON",
            beforeSend:function()
            {
                $('#action_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#action_button').attr('disabled', false);
                if(data.error)
                {
                    if(data.error.first_name_error)
                    {
                        $('#first_name_error').text(data.error.first_name_error);
                    }
                    if(data.error.last_name_error)
                    {
                        $('#last_name_error').text(data.error.last_name_error);
                    }
                    if(data.error.age_error)
                    {
                        $('#age_error').text(data.error.age_error);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data.success+'</div>');

                    $('#action_modal').modal('hide');

                    $('#sample_data').DataTable().destroy();

                    load_data();

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#message').html('');
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        });

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){

        var id = $(this).data('id');

        $('#dynamic_modal_title').text('Edit Data');

        $('#action').val('Edit');

        $('#action_button').text('Edit');

        $('.text-danger').text('');

        $('#action_modal').modal('show');

        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id:id, action:'fetch_single'},
            dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#first_name').val(data.first_name);
                $('#last_name').val(data.last_name);
                $('#gender').val(data.gender);
                $('#age').val(data.age);
                $('#id').val(data.id);
            }
        });

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){

        var id = $(this).data('id');

        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this data?"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{action:'delete', id:id},
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data.success+'</div>');
                    $('#sample_data').DataTable().destroy();
                    load_data();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#message').html('');
                    }, 5000);
                }
            });
        }

    });

});

</script>
```

action.php

```
``
<?php

//action.php

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    $file = 'data.json';

    if($_POST['action'] == 'Add' ||$_POST['action'] == 'Edit')
    {
        $error = array();

        $data = array();

        $data['id'] = time();

        if(empty($_POST['first_name']))
        {
            $error['first_name_error'] = 'First Name is Required';
        }
        else
        {
            $data['first_name'] = trim($_POST['first_name']);
        }

        if(empty($_POST['last_name']))
        {
            $error['last_name_error'] = 'Last Name is Required';
        }
        else
        {
            $data['last_name'] = trim($_POST['last_name']);
        }

        $data['gender'] = trim($_POST['gender']);

        if(empty($_POST['age']))
        {
            $error['age_error'] = 'Age is required';
        }
        else
        {
            $data['age'] = trim($_POST['age']);
        }

        if(count($error) > 0)
        {
            $output = array(
                'error'     =>  $error
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $file_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

            if($_POST['action'] == 'Add')
            {

                $file_data[] = $data;

                file_put_contents($file, json_encode($file_data));

                $output = array(
                    'success' => 'Data Added'
                );
            }

            if($_POST['action'] == 'Edit')
            {
                $key = array_search($_POST['id'], array_column($file_data, 'id'));

                $file_data[$key]['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];

                $file_data[$key]['last_name'] = $data['last_name'];

                $file_data[$key]['age'] = $data['age'];

                $file_data[$key]['gender'] = $data['gender'];

                file_put_contents($file, json_encode($file_data));

                $output = array(
                    'success' => 'Data Edited'
                );
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    if($_POST['action'] == 'fetch_single')
    {
        $file_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

        $key = array_search($_POST["id"], array_column($file_data, 'id'));

        echo json_encode($file_data[$key]);
    }

    if($_POST['action'] == 'delete')
    {
        $file_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

        $key = array_search($_POST['id'], array_column($file_data, 'id'));

        unset($file_data[$key]);

        file_put_contents($file, json_encode($file_data));

        echo json_encode(['success' => 'Data Deleted']);

    }
}

?>
``
```

Comment: "Code is not working" doesn't say much. Please be more specific, say what issue you have, what is expected behavior and what happens instead.

Comment: Code is fine. I wanted the code to work on Ubuntu 20.04 web server since I'm unable to run on Ubuntu 20.04 only. No problem elsewhere.